# Convert query to view or table value function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the cheapest productvariant for all products. For one product it is easy however I can't get my head around doing it for all of them and I don't want to use a cursor.

```
select top 1
    pv.VariantID
from
    ProductVariant pv
    inner join (select min(price) as Price from productvariant where ProductID = @ProductID) pr
        on pv.Price = pr.Price
where
    pv.ProductID = @ProductID
```

This works if the 2 tables have the following structure:

```
Product - ProductID
ProductVariant - ProductID, VariantID, Price
```

I know you can do this, does anyone know how?

Is the best way to turn the query above into a scalar function and use that? So it would become:

```
select
    ProductID
    , dbo.NewFunction(ProductID)
from
    Product
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ProductID, MIN(Price) MinPrice
FROM Product JOIN ProductVariant ON Product.ProductID = ProductVariant.ProductID
GROUP BY ProductID
```

That gets you the minimum price. If you want the VariantID that goes with it, then you need to join once more - BUT is the price unique per VariantID?

```
SELECT VariantID, ProductID, MinPrice
FROM ProductVariant JOIN
     (SELECT ProductID, MIN(Price) MinPrice
     FROM Product JOIN ProductVariant ON Product.ProductID = ProductVariant.ProductID
     GROUP BY ProductID) min_price
     ON ProductVariant.ProductID = min_price.ProductID AND ProductVariant.Price = min_price.MinPrice
```

If the price is not unique per variant, this will not work right - specifically you will get duplicates. If that happens you could change it to:

```
SELECT MIN(VariantID) SmallestVariantID, ProductID, MinPrice
FROM ProductVariant JOIN
     (SELECT ProductID, MIN(Price) MinPrice
     FROM Product JOIN ProductVariant ON Product.ProductID = ProductVariant.ProductID
     GROUP BY ProductID) min_price
     ON ProductVariant.ProductID = min_price.ProductID AND ProductVariant.Price = min_price.MinPrice
GROUP BY ProductID, MinPrice
```

That will pick the smallest variant ID out of the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    pv.ProductID
    , min(pv.VariantID)
from
    ProductVariant pv
    inner join (select min(price) as Price, ProductID from productvariant group by ProductID) pr
        on pv.ProductID = pr.ProductID
        and pr.Price = pv.Price
group by
    pv.ProductID
```

This is the simplest solution I have found.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
select  pv.VariantID
from    ProductVariant pv1
join    (select min(pv2.price) as Price from productvariant pv2 where pv2.ProductID = pv.ProductID) pr
        on pv1.Price = pr.Price
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have multiple products, each with its own variants, and each variant with its own price.

If that is the case, I think

```
select p.ProductID, min(pv.Price)
from Product
  inner join ProductVariant pv on p.ProductID = pv.ProductID
```

would be the simplest query to provide the result.